# Subtract 4 months from a pair of year/month values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to subtract 4 months, the period is defined as year and month:

```
UPDATE [MAS_YCA].[dbo].[temp_AR_SalesPersonhistory]
SET FiscalYear = year(DATEADD(month,-4,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month,cast(FiscalPeriod as Int),DATEADD(year,cast(FiscalYear as Int)-1900,0))))),
FiscalPeriod = right('00'+cast(month(DATEADD(month,-4,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(month,cast(FiscalPeriod as Int),DATEADD(year,cast(FiscalYear as Int)-1900,0))))) as varchar),02)
GO
```

The error I'm getting is `Adding value to a datetime column caused an overflow.`

The fields fiscal year and period are both defined as varchar in the datable.

Comment: What is the data in the fiscalyear and fiscalperiod columns?

Comment: You need to show some sample data, because it isn't really clear what `FiscalYear` and `FiscalPeriod` look like. You said they're year and month `varchar` values, but details like leading zeros could be an issue. And why are you storing integers as `varchar` values?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to check the data in the FiscalYear and FiscalPeriod columns. Most likely, you have an invalid year in the Fiscal year column.

The date range in SQL Server is  January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999. So any year outside this will cause your error.

An easy check (edit, added null and empty string cases):

```
Select * from [MAS_YCA].[dbo].[temp_AR_SalesPersonhistory]
where cast(FiscalYear as Int) > 9999 or cast(FiscalYear as Int) < 1753
or FiscalYear is NULL or FiscalYear = ''
```

Comment: It did not return any rows.

Comment: Updated. Also check for null and empty strings. But my point is that something in that column (or potentially the months column, but less likely) is outside SQL servers date range, so start looking for that.